# Different results when retrieving data from different environments

Tags: linux, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I've completed a project in my local environment running Windows 10. The production server has Debian OS

I encountered an issue. Despite both my local env and prod env being run on the same Cakephp version, version 3.1.4, the following Cakephp database query

```
 $this->Articles->find()->contain('ArticleComments');
```

is returning two different results from an identical database stored in two different environments.

Attached an image which contains both results.

Any idea what could be the problem? From Cakephp point of view configuration is set correctly. In my local env the application and database queries are running smoothly.

Image: [image]

Comment: You're not showing enough context. Can you prove that your databases have similar content to begin with? Also, can you output the SQL queries being executed? Having CakePHP's "Debug Kit" helps a lot. http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/debug-kit.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have an older PHP version on your Debian Server, one that doesn't yet support the magic `__debugInfo()` method (available as of PHP 5.6.0), which is used by Cakes Query class to decorate the debug output with custom information.

If you'd use Cakes `debug()` function you should get identical results (AFAIR).

See also

- **http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.debuginfo**
- **[Source > \Cake\ORM\Query::__debugInfo()](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.1.4/src/ORM/Query.php#L1015)**

Comment: Hi ndm. You were right. Debian server had version 5.4 and my Windows 10 machine had 5.6 version of PHP. I upgraded the Debian to 5.6 however  the issue remains there :(

Comment: @MatthewBarbara Have you ensured that you're actually _running_ 5.6 (`debug(phpversion())`)?

Comment: Yes however I did not restart apache on  the Debian server. The result was the same as on my Windows machine after upgrading  to PHP 5.6 and restarting apache. thanks for your answer